# System.Drawing was not found when VersFx.Formaters.Text.Epub was installed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use `EpubReader` from [VersFx.Formaters.Text.Epub](https://github.com/versfx/EpubReader) assembly. I want to load `EpubBook` into my platforms specific code and then put my own `Book` class into shared code. It looks like this:

```
public interface IEpubReader
    {
        Book ReadEpub(string bookPath);
    }

public class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Chapters { get; set; }
    }

public class DroidEpubReader : IEpubReader
    {
        public Book ReadEpub(string bookPath)
        {
            EpubBook epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(bookPath);
            Book book = new Book
            {
                Title = epubBook.Title,
                Author = epubBook.Author,
                Chapters = epubBook.Chapters.First().SubChapters.Select(sc => sc.Title.ToString())
            };

            return book;
        }
    }
```

`Book` and `IEpubReader` come from shared code.

I got an error when I built my solution.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
>   for Android profile? Filename: 'System.Drawing.dll'    in
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    in
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    in
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() EpubReaderXamarinForms.Droid

I wanted to add manually add `System.Drawing` to my Android project. I found two similar assemblies into COM (System.Drawing.dll version 2.4 and System.Drawing.dll version 2.0), but I got an another error.

[image]

Please can you explain me what I do wrong?

My `package.config` of shared code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.3.193" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

`package.config` of Android project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="VersFx.Formats.Text.Epub" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.3.193" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Drawing is highly dependent on Win32, which only exists in Windows.  It is it not available in Xamarin beyond a few simple classes.

You may be able to modify the source of the library to remove the dependency on System.Drawing, or to replace it with a cross platform drawing library like SkiaSharp.

Comment: Thank you. I think about rewriting source code of this library.